# What is the significance of the ending line of Brokeback Mountain?

Tags: dialogue, ending, brokeback-mountain

The last words in Ang Lee's movie Brokeback Mountain (2005) are:

> Jack, I swear...

said by the protagonist, Ennis del Mar. What is he going to swear?

Comment: IIRC it's deliberately left open-ended.

Comment: It could also just be an expression of incredulity.  Meaning something like "I can't believe you" or "you can't be serious."  The full sentence would be "I swear to God" but people sometimes drop the God part to avoid "taking the Lord's name in vain."

Answer (score 1):

One small thing I realized was that it was an unfinished line, left unknowing forever, which is what you're left with Jack passing, as the character, or even as the viewer. However this is biased because I have never been so moved by a movie.